# How can we use only 1 config out of multiple kubernetes config in pulumi

Tags: typescript, amazon-eks, pulumi

We have 5 EKS clusters and configs are defined in same folder location. When I try to create a resource, as the stack path is common for all clusters, my resource is getting deployed in all clusters. I have to provide a condition to deploy in a single cluster.

[image]

We use github actions and in the workflows, the common stack path is declares. I am new to pulumi and typescripting, trying to figure out where i can provide condition to deploy only in single cluster with the existing setup. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With infrastructure automation tools like Pulumi or Terraform, you usually code the setup of how you want our infrastructure to be.

In Pulumi, you code your infrastructure in a project. The documentation of what a Pulumi project is can be found here:

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/project/

When you want to set this up a number of times, you use different stacks for that. Here are the docs on `Stacks`:

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/stack/

Off interest is this sentence in the opening paragraph:

> Stacks are commonly used to denote different phases of development (such as `development`, `staging`, and `production`) or feature branches (such as `feature-x-dev`).

You can put environment specific configuration in the stack config file (YAML). When using stacks, you end up with this in your source structure:

```
Pulumi.yaml       // <- Pulumi project file
Pulumi.dev.yaml   // <- Config for stack `dev`
Pulumi.prod.yaml  // <- Config for stack `prod`
```

I limit stack configuration to aspects like resource names, sizing config like amount of nodes, etc but not to have flags which lead to creating more/less resources. I explicitely do not want drift between my environments.

How I do it is exactly the opposite of what you want to achieve. I never have Typescript files resembling an environment.

Can you elaborate more on what the differences between your environments are?